# On android of react-native-modalize swipe is not working

Tags: android, react-native, swipe, gesture, react-native-modalize

On android of react-native-modalize it is not possible to close the modal by swipe. On IOS it is working perfect with out any bugs, even ScrollView inside of modal. I tried to add properties but it does not work:

```
panGestureComponentEnabled={true}
panGestureEnabled={true}
```

My config:

```
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.2",
"react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
```

Please can you share your experience how to solve this bug on android.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the decision. You need to wrap your app component into GestureHandlerRootView like this:
App.tsx

```
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from "react-native-gesture-handler"

const App = () => {

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <YourAppComponent />
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  )
}
```